# Reconciling Wikipedia and textbook descriptions of ladder operator method

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, notation

I'm trying to reconcile the work in my textbook, *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model* by Schwartz, which I'm finding difficult to follow, with the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method) for the *ladder operator method* of *quantum harmonic oscillators*.

The Wikipedia article proceeds as follows:

> The commutation property yields
>
> $$\begin{align} Na^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle &= (a^{\dagger} N + [N, a^{\dagger}]) \mid n \rangle \\ &= (a^{\dagger} N + a^{\dagger}) \mid n \rangle \\ &= (n + 1)a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle\end{align}$$
>
> and similarly,
>
> $N a \mid n \rangle = (n - 1)a \mid n \rangle$

I understood everything, except the first part:

> $$ Na^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle = (a^{\dagger} N + [N, a^{\dagger}]) \mid n \rangle $$

1. How did they get this? What "commutation property" is being referred to for this?

The textbook proceeds as follows:

> $$\begin{align} \hat{N} a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle &= a^{\dagger} a a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle \\ &= a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle + a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} a \mid n \rangle \\ &= (n + 1) a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle \end{align}$$

2. Here, I don't understand how the author got

> $$a^{\dagger} a a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle = a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle + a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} a \mid n \rangle$$

and

> $$a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle + a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} a \mid n \rangle = (n + 1) a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle$$

?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Both of these descriptions should have defined the commutator for $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$, and defined $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{a}^\dagger$ (where I'm begin explicit that these are operators) in terms of position and momentum. From that you can deduce the commutator of the ladder operators and then those lines should be transparent. So,l where along that chain are you losing the thread?

Comment: @dmckee They define the *commutators*, but I'm unsure how these lead to the results I mentioned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 -This is simply the definition of a commutator:

$$[N,a^\dagger] := N a^\dagger - a^\dagger N$$

so:
$$Na^\dagger = a^\dagger N + [N,a^\dagger]$$

2 - Remember the commutation relation for the ladder operators $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$:

$$a^\dagger a a^\dagger = a^\dagger (a^\dagger a + [a,a^\dagger]) = a^\dagger a^\dagger a  + a^\dagger 1 = a^\dagger a^\dagger a  + a^\dagger$$

$\quad$ Meaning that:
$$a^\dagger a a^\dagger |n \rangle =  a^\dagger a^\dagger a |n \rangle  + a^\dagger |n \rangle$$

3 - Remember that $a^\dagger a \equiv N$, so:

$$a^\dagger |n \rangle + a^\dagger \underbrace{a^\dagger a}_{N} |n \rangle = a^\dagger |n \rangle + a^\dagger N |n \rangle = (1+n) a^\dagger |n \rangle$$

Answer (score 1):

1) This follows from the definition of the commutator. Since
$$[N,a^\dagger] = N a^\dagger - a^\dagger N,$$
we have
$$N a^\dagger = a^\dagger N + N a^\dagger - a^\dagger N  =  a^\dagger N + [N,a^\dagger].$$

2) Since the commutator is
$$[a,a^\dagger] = aa^\dagger - a^\dagger a = 1$$
we have
$$aa^\dagger = 1 + a^\dagger a,$$
which should make the first statement clear (simply insert). Since $a^\dagger a = N$, you can insert
$$(a^\dagger + a^\dagger N) | n \rangle$$
as a step between the second and third lines. Then insert the result from your first quote.