# Reconciling Wikipedia and textbook descriptions of ladder operator method #2

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, harmonic-oscillator, notation

I'm trying to reconcile the work in my textbook, *Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model* by Schwartz, which I'm finding difficult to follow, with the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator#Ladder_operator_method) for the *ladder operator method* of *quantum harmonic oscillators*.

The Wikipedia article proceeds as follows:

> The commutation property yields
>
> $$\begin{align} Na^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle &= (a^{\dagger} N + [N, a^{\dagger}]) \mid n \rangle \\ &= (a^{\dagger} N + a^{\dagger}) \mid n \rangle \\ &= (n + 1)a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle\end{align}$$
>
> and similarly,
>
> $N a \mid n \rangle = (n - 1)a \mid n \rangle$

I understand this.

However, the textbook proceeds differently:

> $$\begin{align} \hat{N} a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle &= a^{\dagger} a a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle \\ &= a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle + a^{\dagger} a^{\dagger} a \mid n \rangle \\ &= (n + 1) a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle \end{align}$$
>
> Thus, $a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle = C \mid n + 1 \rangle$ for some constant $C$, which can be chosen real. We can determine $C$ from the normalization $\langle n \mid n \rangle = 1$:
>
> $$\begin{align} C^2 &= \langle n + 1 \mid C^2 \mid n + 1 \rangle \\ &= \langle n \mid a a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle \\ &= \langle n \mid (a^{\dagger} a + 1) \mid n \rangle \\ &= n + 1, \end{align}$$
>
> so $C = \sqrt{n + 1}$. Similarly, $a \mid n \rangle = C' \mid n - 1 \rangle$ and
>
> $$C'^2 = \langle n - 1 \mid C'^2 \mid n - 1 \rangle = \langle n \mid a^{\dagger} a \mid n \rangle = n,$$
>
> so $C' = \sqrt{n}$. The result is that
>
> $$a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle = \sqrt{n + 1} \mid n + 1 \rangle, \ a \mid n \rangle = \sqrt{n} \mid n - 1 \rangle.$$

I am seeking clarification about the following:

1. How can the author conclude that then $a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle = C \mid n + 1 \rangle$ for some constant $C$? Where did the $C \mid n + 1 \rangle$ come from?
2. Why was $C^2$ used here instead of $C$? Was this just a mathematical artefact to make the derivation easier?
3. How did the author get that $\langle n + 1 \mid C^2 \mid n + 1 \rangle = \langle n \mid a a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle$?
4. Am I correct in thinking that the author got from $\langle n \mid a a^{\dagger} \mid n \rangle$ to $\langle n \mid (a^{\dagger} a + 1) \mid n \rangle$ by the fact that if we multiply $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ together we get $H + \dfrac{1}{2}$ (or $a^{\dagger} a = H - \dfrac{1}{2}$, in this case), where $H$ is the Hamiltonian?
5. How did the author get $\langle n \mid (a^{\dagger} a + 1) \mid n \rangle = n + 1$?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494864/2451

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you need to ask about every single step in these derivations, maybe that is an indication that you should start with some easier material. As someone commented on your previous question, QFT books are usually not written for beginners. I strongly recommend spending some time to learn the basics of Quantum Mechanics. Popular books are (for example) Cohen-Tannoudji, Griffiths or Sakurai, they all explain the Harmonic Oscillator in great detail.

Comment: @Noiralef Yes, I was going to leave it after this part and go back to a more basic quantum mechanics text. I just wanted to finish/understand this part of the textbook before I left it.

Comment: @bolbteppa Thanks; that clarifies the main reason behind it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. They just showed that $a^\dagger |n\rangle$ is an eigenvector of $\hat N$ with eigenvalue $n+1$, therefore $a^\dagger |n\rangle$ is proportional to $|n+1\rangle$.
2. The idea behind this calculation is to calculate the square of $a^\dagger |n\rangle$, which happens to be $C^2$.
3. This is again the definition of $C$ (note that $\langle n | a = \langle n + 1 | C$).
4. $aa^\dagger = a^\dagger a + 1$ due to $[a,a^\dagger] = 1$.
5. $a^\dagger a |n\rangle = \hat N | n \rangle = n | n \rangle$ and $\langle n | n \rangle = 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean *eigenvalue* $n + 1$ in 1.?

Comment: Yes, I do, edited.